# if pthread_cond_wait can loss signal when pthread_cond_signal signal before it

Tags: c++

================thread1

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
do 
{
    fun();//this fun will cost a long time, maybe 1-2 second
    gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
    outtime.tv_sec = now.tv_sec + 5;
    outtime.tv_nsec = now.tv_usec * 1000;
    int ret = pthread_cond_timedwait(&cond, &mutex, &outtime);    
} while((!predicate && ret != ETIMEDOUT)
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

==========================thread2

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
predicate = true;
pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

if thread2 send a signal during thread1's fun(), there is no pthread_cond_timedwait, when fun() call return, the phread_cond_timedwait in thread1 still can get the signal that thread2 has sent before or not? can we call a time-consuming fun before pthread_cond_timedwait in while()??

Answer (score 1):

If `pthread_cond_signal` is called when no thread is waiting for a signal it has no effect. The signal is not stored for future use.

If `predicate` is true, the code in the loop should not wait for the condition variable.

Comment: thanks pete becker, what do you think of the fun() i called in loop, i think it's wrong, shouldn't call any function that costs time in while. but i did a test program, the singal can be received by pthread_cond_wait, even though the signal was sent when there was no pthread_cond_wait, but i am not sure if it can received all the time.